# jScrollPane and Cufon together. Can someone make it work?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, cufon

I used cufon inside of my scrollpanel elements as you can see in 
http://www.timersys.com/demos/flatbrook/grass-fed-beef/

Problem is that the bottom of divs are being chop off.

I searched on JScrollpane google groups but there is no solution available. When cufon is there JScrollpane calculates wrong the height.

I already tried to exceute cufon before and after jscrollpane. Also triend to exceute jscrollpane with cufon callback option. But always i get same result.

Anyone  around with a solution that can help?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add any bottom padding to the div containing the jScrollPane?

EDIT: Alright, the above answer is a workaround, but after having gone over your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jennyfofenny/zM4hS/, I believe your answer is to add a Cufon.now() call between your Cufon.replace line and your .jScrollPane() line. This should solve your problem in all scenarios that I've tested for.

Comment: Yes i tried  that but in Firebug. Now i edited the stylesheet and its working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is more of a workaround than a solution... You are fooling jScrollPane into providing space for the text... However, if your text is dynamic and needs two rows of space then you would need to update your stylesheet to reflect this... I'd recommend trying one of the solutions in my answer...

Comment: It may be a workaround, but if none of your solutions work, than it's better than nothing.

Comment: Nice one! That's a much better and more flexible solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jScrollPane doesn't know how big the text will be once cufon has done its substitution... So it incorrectly calculates the height of the content. The correct solution should be to use the cufon complete callback to initialise jScrollPane but you say you tried that and it didn't work...

Do you have a page showing how it looked when you were using the cufon callback? If it really doesn't work then it would suggest a bug in one script or the other...

Another solution would be to use the autoReinitialise setting for jScrollPane e.g.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html

Comment: Using the callback of Cufon it just looked the same as not using it. Havent tried using the auto reinitialise functions tought. Also i sent a message to jscrollpane google group, but never got an answer. Thanks

Comment: I meant how did it look in terms of the code that you wrote... As I say, that is the correct approach and will work in more situations than the current hack... If you can provide an example of a page initialising jScrollPane in the cufon callback which isn't working then I can investigate further and try to provide a fix...